# Stream error when loading an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to send an XML file to a Webservice.

Here's the code that loads the XML and saves it to the stream:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mesServiceURL);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream();
xmlDoc.Save(request_stream);
request_stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream r_stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader response_stream = new
StreamReader(r_stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
string sOutput = response_stream.ReadToEnd();
```

The request_stream object's length property has this :

```
'request_stream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

On disk the XML is 3 kb so it's not huge.

So, how do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `Stream` base class doesn't support the `Length` property. I dont see how this is effecting your code?

Comment: Getting 500 error when the xml is posted to the service. Will post the complete code.

Comment: Why are you closing the underlying stream before reading the response?